# How do you describe a song that was released after the artist's death?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

There are some words for movies released starring actors/actresses who died before their release. There are also similar words for books. But what is the equivalent term for a song or album released after the artist died?

For example, Mac Miller and Michael Jackson are two artists who did this.

Answer (score 2):

Such a release is known as a 'posthumous release.' According to [Oxford Languages,](https://www.google.com/search?q=posthumous) posthumous is an adjective meaning

> occurring, awarded, or appearing after the death of the originator.

And [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/posthumous) gives us:

> published after the death of the author : following or occurring after death

A song, then, could be released posthumously: "Michael Jackson's *Breaking News* was released posthumously."

Also see this post from *[JoinCake.com](https://www.joincake.com/blog/posthumous-album/#:%7E:text=A%20posthumous%20album%20is%20an,released%20after%20an%20artist%27s%20death.)*.